# Render json with status unauthorized, receive response with 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm having some unexpected behavior with rails 4.2 and rspec-rails 3.3. I am responding from the controller with a `render` sending an explicit `:unauthorized` status code:

```
module Authenticable

  # Devise methods overwrites
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
  end

  def authenticate_with_token!
    render json: { errors: "Not authenticated" }, status: :unauthorized unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end
end
```

The failing rspec is this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class Authentication
  include Authenticable
end

describe Authenticable do
  let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }
  subject { authentication }

  ......

describe "#authenticate_with_token" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      authentication.stub(:current_user).and_return(nil)
      response.stub(:response_code).and_return(401)
      response.stub(:body).and_return({"errors" => "Not authenticated"}.to_json)
      authentication.stub(:response).and_return(response)
    end

    it "render a json error message" do
      expect(json_response[:errors]).to eql "Not authenticated"
    end

    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(401) } #<--- fails
  end
```

If I place a `byebug` before the failing test, I see clearly that the response has the "Not authenticated" message, but the status is set to 200

For reference, this is my `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'rgeo'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem "devise"
gem "responders"

gem 'sabisu_rails', github: "IcaliaLabs/sabisu-rails"
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'furatto'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'byebug'
    gem 'pry-byebug', '=1.3.3'
    gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'pry-remote'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.3"
end

group :test do

  #gem "shoulda-matchers"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'ffaker'
end
```

Comment: Ok, something is not fully clear to me. You are testing `Authenticable` module. Why those test looks like controller tests? I can see a lot of stubs, but not a single acting line - where is the line you send a request? In short: more context is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to implement sec. 5.2 of this book http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_five

Comment: Ok, this seems to use old version of RSpec, when it was guessing what sort of test we are in by the location of the file. That solves the mystery of request. still, not the best practice IMO. Now the question is - why do you stub the response? It does very little sense to stub one object and then expect it to be as we stubbed it. In short, you should execute 'authenticate_with_token!` method and then inspect whether resulting response is as it should be. You should be able to use anonymous controller rather than pure ruby object (so you don't need to stub `render` method).